# Rundeck - Disable logging of password field

Tags: rundeck

Kindly help me with any configuration changes that can be done to avoid logging of password field in rundeck logs.

It seems even though password fields are not visible via UI but in rundeck logs it does capture it as a plaintext.

The issue still persists after upgrade to 2.6.8 version of Rundeck. Similar report is https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1780

Can someone post a workaround for this as it is critical to either disable the debug option or fix this.

Thanks

Comment: do you mean, the password shows as plaintext in rundeck service log ?

Comment: did you update to latest version?

Comment: @LeoPrince  Yes it is coming as plaintext in rundeck service log.

Comment: @BMW Is there a way around for  Rundeck v2.2

Comment: I didn't have your problem at 2.5 and 2.6

Comment: Yeah me too using 2.6 and I used 2.5 before as well, never had such an issue. Got to check with 2.2 to see if there any work around..

Comment: @BMW  I upgraded to 2.6.8 but in debug log it shows the password as plaintext RD_SECUREOPTION_PASSWORD=plaintext password.    Did you also have the same issue while running the jobs in Debug mode? Is there a way to disable debug option?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record answer: Right now you can use the [Mask Password](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/log-filters/mask-passwords.html#mask-passwords) output filter to hide any password entries on any step.